# Ubuntu on external HDD. HELP!

Tags: installation, live-usb

Update:
I did how ubuntu_tr told me to do. Ubuntu installs successfully.
But when i boot with the HDD, this error shows up:

Error: Partition is undiscoverable
Grub Rescue >_ [I could type some command here]

Any idea?

Orignal:
OK, all I want is a bootable installation on my external HDD.

I want Ubuntu to boot on any computer I plug into.
Is it possible?

Can someone point me to detailed instructions of doing so?

Comment: You can create a persistent live USB stick.

Comment: What's the other way to do it if you don't live install? Never heard of a second way to do it in...

Comment: No, I mean while doing that, I still want to  keep some apps installed and settings preserved for every use.

Comment: Are you using Windows? Or Ubuntu?

Comment: You'll get much worse performance than you would get if the same type of HDD was an internal drive and you had a dual boot setup with Ubuntu installed on it. Consider this: every time you do anything to your system if it is installed on an external USB HDD, it has to send information through the USB port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First you should create an installation media (DVD/USB). If there is one, you can use it.
2. Boot with this installation media and select install
3. Plug in the external HDD/USB to your computer.
4. Select "Something Else" option on What to do page.
5. Choose your external HDD/USB as the installating area (/ for mount point)
6. And also choose **grub to install** on this ext HDD not computer
   HDD. (sdb, sdc, sdd or whatever it is from the dropdown menu). You should prefer the first partition on it to install Ubuntu.
   The
   information on the partition you select over external HDD will be
   erased.
7. Continue and finish the installation to your ext media.
8. Select your new Ubuntu installed HDD/USB while booting from the list (F12 or your computers startup key to select boot device)

Comment: Hey mate, Today I finally did what you said. But I installed Ubnutu on 2nd partition, and chose '/boot' as mount point. But when I try to boot it from HDD, it says "BootMGR is Missing..." any idea? I am sure I installed boot files to HDD partition.

Comment: I wish you choose just / for mount point and external HDD to install grub. Why you marked /boot ?

Comment: IDK man, maybe I didn't read your comment carefully :P. By'grub' you mean bootloaders, right? Will be back

Comment: Nope, it didn't work either with / mount point. :|